# How do you use a Ternary operator for a WinForm object property?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

How do you use a Ternary operator for a WinForm object property? eg:

```
    private void ToggleControls()
    {
        myBtn.Enabled ? false : true;
    }
```

the above code throws an error.

Comment: You have to take the return value somewhere

Comment: The goal is, everytime this method is called, myBtn.Enabled property is toggled. If it is True we set it to False, if it is False we set it to True.

Comment: I think I wrote the term wrong, its the Ternary operator, not Lambda.

Answer (score 3):

```
  private void ToggleControls()
{
    myBtn.Enabled= myBtn.Enabled==true ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about how the ternary operator works, it will evaluate the left hand side of the question mark (which needs to be a boolean expression), and return one of the two members depending on the truthiness:

```
int age = 80;
string message = age > 50 ? "You're old" : "You're young"; 
// message will be "You're old" because age is greater than 50
```

It is a shorthand for

```
int age = 80;
string message;

if (age > 50)
    message = "You're old";
else
    message = "You're young";
```

Now if the question is about toggling a boolean, you don't even need to use the ternary operator:

```
private void ToggleControls()
{
    myBtn.Enabled = !myBtn.Enabled;
}
```